# Spring Batch Persist Job Meta Data

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I wanted to Persist Spring Batch Meta Data related to Jobs/Steps instead of Using MapJobRepository, as it is not recommended for Production Use.
I have extended DefaultBatchConfigurer and have overridden the methods to use My Primary DataSource and Transaction Manager by using JobRepositoryFactoryBean.
Also i have Registered SimpleJobLauncher bean to use custom job repository , for which i have used the below code

```
@Bean
SimpleJobLauncher simpleJobLauncher() throws Exception {
    SimpleJobLauncher simpleJobLauncher= new SimpleJobLauncher();
    simpleJobLauncher.setTaskExecutor(new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor());
    simpleJobLauncher.setJobRepository(customRepository());
    return simpleJobLauncher;
}

@Bean
public JobRepository customRepository() throws Exception {
JobRepositoryFactoryBean jobRepositoryFactoryBean = new JobRepositoryFactoryBean();
jobRepositoryFactoryBean.setDataSource(myPrimaryDataSource);
jobRepositoryFactoryBean.setTransactionManager(myTransactionManager);
jobRepositoryFactoryBean.setDatabaseType("MYSQL");
jobRepositoryFactoryBean.setTablePrefix("BATCH_");
jobRepositoryFactoryBean.setMaxVarCharLength(1000);
return jobRepositoryFactoryBean.getObject();
}
```

I am facing with below exception when i launch the job

```
java.lang.NullpointerException:null
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.MapJobExecutionDao:synchronizeStatus(MapJobExecutionDao.java 161)
```

Please do let me know where exactly my configuration is wrong.

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine Can you Please throw some light on this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your exception, it looks like Spring Batch is configured to use the Map based job repository and not the persistent one.

Since you extended `DefaultBatchConfigurer`, you need to override `createJobRepository` and return your custom job repository. Declaring a bean of type `JobRepository` in the application context is not sufficient.